# Error: 'duplicate subscripts for columns' on using xmlToDataFrame in r

Tags: r, xml, dataframe, xml-parsing, nodes

I'm parsing an xml file, with these lines:

```
xmlData = xmlParse( paste( dataDirStr, fileName, '.xml', sep='' ) )
```

So far, so good.  But this:

```
listData = xmlToDataFrame( xmlData )
```

produces this unfortunate message:

> Error in [<-.data.frame(*tmp*, i, names(nodes[[i]]), value = c("4B6EW",  : duplicate subscripts for columns

This `xml` file is used by Lockheed-Martin on a daily basis, so they must have a way to handle this problem.  Any help?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24792471/i-find-this-error-message-when-im-using-xml-in-r